# C/C++ - Integers clashing with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, int

I've been working on a small library collection, and in my n-dimensional geometric vector template class, I've run into an issue between two constructors. The constructor `VectorN( t data[n] )` clashes with constructor `VectorN( t value )`, and I get the error:

```
More than one instance of constructor ___ matches the argument list".
```

I understand *why* this is occuring, but a solution eludes me. The issue only occurs when I attempt to instantiate the class using `VectorN(0)`, but when `value` is anything other than 0 the correct constructor is used. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Please post an MCVE.

Comment: It completely makes sense.

Comment: I can't reproduce that with GCC 5.2. A working test case is required. The solution is probably just to use `VectorN((int)0)`.

Comment: C++ has tightened significantly the rules for null pointer literals, so GCC 5.2 may well not exhibit the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You improperly declared constructor that accepts C style array - you are loosing size. If you do that correctly:

```
template <class T>
class VectorN {
public:
    template<std::size_t N>
    VectorN( T (&array)[N] );
    ...
};
```

then problem with 0 would disappear.

Comment: I've been using generic C for so long that I often forget half the STL exists. I want to keep everything as 'generic' as possible and make no assumptions about what data types others use (hence the use of a standard C style array), but I guess implicit conversions make that point moot.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that 0 is a valid null pointer constant, which is a valid T* (which is what t data[n] actually is under the hood). If you really want to take raw C arrays, use a reference to the array- this is strongly typed and safe(r).

Also, raw C arrays are shit. `std::array` is for when you want to not segfault.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array like `t data[n]`, actually you just pass a pointer on the first element of the array. So your first constructor is equal to `VectorN(t* data)`. So now when you call the constructor with zero, the compiler might as well think you want to pass the null-pointer.

I would recommend you to clearly distinguish your constructors. So for example since you have a n-dimensional vector, you have to specify the n somewhere. You could do a constructor like: `VectorN(t* data, int n)`. Than it is definitely clear where you want to use what constructor.

Comment: I guess I should have defined it better, but N is defined in the template declaration. So a 3-dimensional vector of floats would be defined as `VectorN<float, 3>`, and a 15-dimensional vector of snozzberries would be defined as `VectorN<snozzberries, 15>`.